# Set -resultBundlePath directly in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

It is possible with `xcodebuild` to pass a `-resultBundlePath` argument to specify the directory where a result bundle describing what occurred will be placed. I'm trying to find a similar option directly in Xcode but I cannot seem to find it.

Does someone know if it is actually possible to specify a folder for the result bundle directly in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

1. Within Xcode, go to File/Workspace Settings (or Project Setting if not within a workspace):

[image]

2. Press on the "Advanced..." button

[image]

3. There you can change the build location:

[image]

Comment: That's to change the path to the DerivedData which does contain the Test results but also contains many other things I'm not interested in. The structure of the test result folder is also not the same as when you pass a -resultBundlePath to Xcode.